# Error Restarting Apache - "SSLCACertificateFile takes one argument"

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, digital-certificate

I am trying to set up SSL for my website. In my Apache website hosts file I am using:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/www.website.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/www.website.com.key
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 1
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/ca-client.pem
```

I am getting this error message when restarting Apache:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                          [fail]
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 25 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website.com.conf:
SSLCACertificateFile takes one argument, SSL CA Certificate file ('/path/to/file' - PEM encoded)
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

If I comment out the SSLCACertifcateFile lines, the website works perfectly. As expected the SSL is "Not Trusted" without the CACertificate.

How can I debug this to figure out why I can't include the SSLCACertificateFile? What does the error mean?

Answer (score 7):

You say your 'hosts' file had the SSLCACertificateFile line, maybe that is the problem? Move it to your virtual website config file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/**yourwebsite.com**.conf) or to your default config file if that's what you're using (same directory but default.conf or 000-default.conf)

I'm not exactly sure what your problem is, but for me I had a **comment** after the SSLCACertificateFile line in my site conf.
I am using debian 8.5

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourwebsite.com.conf
```

I had a comment after it, like so

```
SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem  #comment
```

I removed it and it worked again

```
SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem
```

Also be sure you have a TAB after SSLCACertificateFile, instead of a space.

Another thought would be, are you using *service apache2 reload* or *service apache2 restart*...? I'd suggest giving restart a try and see (if it's reload that isn't working).

Answer (score 0):

This error may also happen on Windows Apache installations if folder to `.pem` or `.crt` file contains whitespaces.

Instead of:

```
SSLCertificateFile C:\Users\John Doe\AppData\Roaming\letsencrypt-win-simple\httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org\example.org-crt.pem
```

Use quotes:

```
SSLCertificateFile "C:\Users\John Doe\AppData\Roaming\letsencrypt-win-simple\httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org\example.org-crt.pem"
```